# Percentage in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find the percentage between two columns and I tried this :

```
select
(count(id)* 100.0 /(select count(id) FROM db.table  where log = '40')) as percentage
from db.table;
```

And the result is this:

```
418659.800405426477
```

Why the output number is like that?
Also is there any way to make it look better and help end users to understand the percentage?

Comment: Are you concerned about the value being large or the number of decimal places?  Also to get a percentage you would normally divide the smaller number by the total then multiply by 100 ... e.g. if ```COUNT(id)``` = 100 for simplicity and ```count(id) where log = '40'``` was 30 then you would want (30 / 100) * 100 = 30 as the percentage

Comment: I personally, as well, suggest providing the percentage as a decimal, which means *not* multiplying it by `100`. A value like `418659.800405426477` as a percentage is `41,865,980.04%`, and a value like `102` would be `10200%`. `1` is `100%` and `0.95` would be `95%`. Then, if the user wants it displayed as a percentage, then application can handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is like that because of the rules that SQL Server uses when doing arithmetic on numbers -- the precision and scale are rather details (note that 1.0 is a numeric constant).

The explanation for this is in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).  Note that even I don't bother trying to understand the rules for division.

I just want to point out that you can simplify the query:

```
select avg(case when log = '40' then 100.0 else 0 end) as percentage
from db.table;
```

This only scans the table once, so it should be faster.  But it should produce a similar result.

If you want a given scale/precision then use `round()`, `floor()`, `ceil()`, `str()` or convert to a numeric.

Comment: Whilst this approach works, I think the use of `Avg()` makes the code tricky to comprehend. I would suggest `SELECT Count(*) / Sum(CASE WHEN log = '40' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100...` instead.

Comment: @gvee . . . We'll just agree to disagree.

Comment: Absolutely fair enough, Gordon! Agree to disagree :)